# Replace only one element and not all

Tags: jquery, replace

Ok, I tried this myself before posting here, but at this point I ran into a wall.

I have a list of products, each product has an '*Add To Cart*' button/image, and I want that image to be replaced with the '*Item added to Cart*' image.

The problem I have is that when I replace one image, all images are replaced. You can now tell how new to jQuery I am.

This is my jQuery:

```
//Replace the 'Add To Cart' button
 $('.add-to-cart-btn').click(function(){
   $('.add-to-cart-btn').replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart">');
 return false;
 });
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart-btn"><img src="images/button-add-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart"></a>
```

As you can see, I'm replacing the entire ahref element because when the item is added, I don't want that button to be clickable again.

Any idea how to make just that one specific 'Add To Cart' button/image get replaced and not all the buttons?

Thanks for any help and guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to only replace the item that you selected (AKA, the item that was clicked), so don't do the selection again and instead use the object that was clicked (this).

```
//Replace the 'Add To Cart' button
 $('.add-to-cart-btn').click(function(){
   $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Add to Cart">');
 return false;
 });
```

Comment: $(this), doh! Wow, now I know. Thanks for your help JasCav.

Comment: JasCav, I as thinking: What if I want to fade in the new image? I tried "$(this).fadeIn('<img src="images/button-added-to-cart.png" alt="Item added to Cart">');" but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more efficient way to do this would be:

```
$('.add-to-cart-btn').click(function() {
    this.src = 'images/button-added-to-cart.png';
    this.alt = 'Item added to Cart';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Ricardo It does, at least in principle. I made a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/awncb/) showing it working. This is preferable since it modifies in place so it should be a smoother process.

Comment: Mmmm, you're right Marcus. I still don't get why it's preferable to the solution above. I tried giving you a vote but this thing is telling me that I already voted 2 days ago and my vote is locked or something... Thanks!

Comment: @Richardo For a start it is preferable since you do not have to convert the `this` into a jQuery object using `$(this)` as in @JasCav's answer. That means it is more efficient. Here I am right down at the bare metal altering the nodes attributes.